# Gate XOR logic in java

Tags: java

folks... the XOR Gate is still giving me a hard time. I'm really close to finishing it but some of the test cases are failing. My specs say that if I have `more than two` of `1` (High Signals) such as: 
`111100` or `111` or `11` or `00` or `0000` so the output should be `0` (Low Signal).

Else if any input signal is 'X' the output is also `X` such as 
`XX00111` or `XX10` or `0X01` then the output should also be `X`

Else if all the input signals are known (no `X` signals) and there is `EXACTLY` one `1` signal then the output is `1` such as 
`000001` or `10000` or `01` or `10` then the output should be `1`

Note: All of the getters and setter methods are correct (tested) and `Signal.HI ==1, Signal.LO = 0 and Signal.X = X`. 
Could smb help me with this method? When the inputs signals are `011` the output should be `0` when Im getting `1`. Secondly, when the inputs are `XX` Im getting `0` when it should be `X`. Could smb please hint me or help me? Thanks in advance!

```
@Override
    public boolean propagate() 
    {
        Signal inputSignal;

        int countHI = 0;
        List<Wire> inputs = getInputs();
        Signal temp = getOutput().getSignal();

        for(int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++)
        {
            inputSignal = inputs.get(i).getSignal();

            if(inputSignal == Signal.X)
            {

                getOutput().setSignal(Signal.X);
                break;
            }

            else if(inputSignal == Signal.HI) 
                countHI++;

            else if(inputSignal == Signal.LO)
                getOutput().setSignal(Signal.HI);

        }
        if(countHI > 2 || countHI == 0)
            getOutput().setSignal(Signal.LO);
```

....................................further unnecessary code for this problem

Comment: You're making the same mistake again. Don't set the result from inside the loop. Test if there is an X and set a boolean variable if so (and break out of the loop once found), and count the number of HI. Then, AFTER the loop, test the value of your  X boolean, test if the number of HI is 1, and set the appropriate output signal.

Comment: @JBNizet, so I have to setSignal after the loop? Just making sure that if X is found then any assigned boolean value turns to true and breaks from loop? I just do not get when you say " test the value of your X boolean" after the loop. Could you please give any example with testing the value of any variable's boolean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would code it. Note that I only set the signal when I'm sure that it's the correct value: after the loop.

Also note that I make all the cases mutually exclusive.

```
boolean hasX = false;
boolean hiCount = 0;

for (Wire wire : inputs) {
    Signal inputSignal = wire.getSignal();

    if (inputSignal == Signal.X) {
        hasX = true;
        // optimization: break out of the loop early since we know
        // that, whatever the number of HI and LO, if there is one
        // X, the result is X
        break;
    }
    else if (inputSignal == Signal.HI) 
        hiCount++;
    }
}

if (hasX) {
    getOutput().setSignal(Signal.X);
}
else if (hiCount == 1) {
    getOutput().setSignal(Signal.HI);
}
else {
    getOutput().setSignal(Signal.LO);
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, @JBNizet! One last question: why would not it be more useful to do it with regular for loop as I did in my way? I mean, I traced/read my code over and over again and seems logically for a person correct. What could have been wrong with XOR code because I've implemented the code also for AND, OR, NOT gates the way I tried to do in the original method. Thanks again! @JBNizet

Comment: The problem in the code is not the for loop. The problem is the logic: you overwrite the X output with another one based on the number os 1 and 0. And your condition > 2 is wrong. See @Braheem's answer. You should prefer the foreach loop whenever possible: it's as fast as it can whatever the collection is. Your kind of loop is fast with an ArrayList, but horribly slow with a LinkedList. It's also less readable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what is happening:

When you are detecting an input signal of X, you are setting the output as X, and breaking out of the loop... but the last IF statement is still being executed, and so because your input is 'XX', countHI is zero, and so the last if condition is satisfied and you end up overriding the output signal by setting it to 0 at the end of your code. The break only breaks out of the loop it is currently in.

Your code only checks if hiCount is greater than 2 in the last if statement, but you expect it to be false when there are two or more 1's, so when you have exactly two 1's, you do not enter that if condition.

You need to think about your solution logically and run through it yourself and then you will realize why it is not working as you expect.